# Is it possible to remap <Ctrl + i> to be <F8>?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

As simple as it sounds I can't seem to figure out how to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to be <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Reason being is that Emacs recognizes the key sequences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
to be <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> respectively.

So for a workaround I'm simply trying to remap the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
to <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> respectively 
system wide.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what?  Ctrl-I and Ctrl-M **are** TAB and CR.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and <kbd>Return</kbd> keys insert the control sequences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>, respectively. There is no way for an application running in this environment to distinguish them.

Emacs can and does distinguish the keys from their corresponding control sequences in graphical mode, e.g. X Windows.  In this case, you can simply use `global-set-key` or similar as normal.

If you want to use these particular sequences for other things in the terminal, you will have to catch and change the inputs before they reach the terminal. You could use `xbindkeys` along with `xdotool`. That would look something like this:

```
# .xbindkeysrc
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers F8"
    control+i

"xdotool key --clearmodifiers F9"
    control+m
```

Comment: That's what I opted to do. It sounds like I'd have to mess with the terminal drivers to get the config that I want. And that would make my config less portable in the long run.